# Redirecting to previous page without reloading

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, caching

I have a question that suppose, I have an Admin Dashboard page, on which I have given a list of users. clicking upon a particular user the details of corresponding user is shown on a different page (say on userDetails.jsp). Now I have a back button on userDetails page, Clicking of which I need to redirect admin to the last visited page that is Admin Dashboard page, I have one solution that I can "Reload" the previos page on clicking back button, but then I feel that there is the overhead of calling a server side API, retrieving all the data, Again redraw the whole admin dashboard page even when there is no change made in the userDetails[because it is read only page, modification is not allowed there]. Is there anyway that I can make user of cache or anything else so that I will not need to go to the server to fetch all the data again. I am using spring MVC, angularjs, Thank you.

Comment: The browser caches GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your button's click event add the following code:

`$window.history.back();`

make sure to use `$window` rather than `window` since you're using AngularJS

Comment: Will it not make a server call.?

Comment: only if you have an event handler that would automatically redirect when your page activates, but in general not. try it.